# Проблема с 8080 портом

Tags: ubuntu, port

Ребята, случайно ввёл не на том сервере команды:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

Теперь на сайте ошибка: Could not connect to the server. domain:8080
Помогите, пожалуйста, что нужно изменить, чтобы вновь всё заработало.

Comment: iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

Comment: sudo ufw deny 8080

Comment: Применять с превеликой осторожностью. Ибо это всего лишь противоположности Ваших команд. Неизвестно улучшат ли они ситуацию или усугубят.

Comment: Чтобы получит правильный ответ, надо задать правильный вопрос.

Comment: 1) сохранить нынешний конфиг ipTables 
2) сбросить все и восстанавливать постепенно, добавляя каждую команду